# Using socket.io modules in other JS files

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

The following is my app.js that I configured for socket.io functionality, The things are working as expected ,but now i want to use this socket functionality another js file from the same project, How to achieve this?

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write `var io = require('socket.io')(server);` in each file where you want to use `socket.io` module. If you want to create shared functionality, create another module in your app with `socket.io`, ie.:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

module.exports = function(options) {
  // your code here
}
```

If its not the answer for your question, please be more specific.

Comment: If i write var io = require('socket.io')(server); in each file where i want to use socket.io module Iam getting ReferenceError: server is not defined error

Comment: Well, you are passing in a variable `(server)` so you have to create this variable exactly as in you example. So add before the rest of requirements (http, express). Like i said, if you want you can create module function which return to you already created socket.io object. Otherwise you have to insert in each file all 3 statements.

EDIT:
Read about node.js module first: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html